# Regexp groovy

Tags: regex, groovy

I need a regexp to find strings that start with a specific word then comes colon and whitespace for example

```
"ErrorID: blabla"
```

Please help. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work fine:

```
^(\w+): (.+)$
```

First match group will give the first word (e.g. `ErrorID`), second the rest (e.g. `blabla`).

Exact implementation would depend on the programming language you use.

Comment: @Natalia Don't forget to mark the question as accepted (tick under the answser that you have choosen).

Answer (score 2):

This should do what you want:

```
^ErrorID: .*$
```